# Transforming a nested environment into a nested list

Tags: r, list, recursion, environment

I really think I'm missing something totally obvious here, but I just can't put my finger on it: how can I combine `rapply()` and either `as.list()` or `eapply()` or both in order to **recursively** convert a nested `environment` into a nested `list`.

What I'm actually after is something like `as.list(<env>, recursive=TRUE)` and I thought that `rapply()` would somehow be usefull in this.

That's the nested environment:

```
env <- new.env()
env$world <- new.env()
env$world$europe <- new.env()
env$world$europe$germany <- new.env()
env$world$europe$germany$foo <- 1
env$world$europe$germany$bar <- 2
```

That's the structrue I'd like to end up with:

```
env.as.list <- list(
    world=list(europe=list(germany=list(foo=1, bar=2)))
)

> env.as.list
$world
$world$europe
$world$europe$germany
$world$europe$germany$foo
[1] 1

$world$europe$germany$bar
[1] 2
```

And rather than building some slow recursive function based on `lapply()`, I would like to make use of the fast `.Internal()` function in `rapply()`.

But as `rapply` is meant to work on `lists`, of course it will "stop" once it hits an `environment`:

```
> rapply(as.list(env), as.list, how="list")
$world
$world$europe
<environment: 0x000000001748d640>
```

What's the trick here?

Comment: You mentioned eapply -- f = function(x) if (is.environment(x)) eapply(x, f) else x.

Comment: Thanks! Quite obvious once you see it ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Custom function:

`rapply` is only for nested lists; use recursion.

```
nested_env_list <- function(env) {
  out <- as.list(env)
  lapply(out, function(x) if (is.environment(x)) nested_env_list(x) else x)
}
```

---

Example:

```
 > env <- new.env(); env$a <- new.env(); env$a$b <- 1; env$a$c <- 2; env$d <- 4
 > dput(nested_env_list(env))
 structure(list(a = structure(list(b = 1, c = 2), .Names = c("b", "c")), d = 4), .Names = c("a", "d"))
```

---

### Replace built-in `as.list`:

You can also replace the behavior of `as.list` to ensure this happens throughout whenever you pass an environment to `as.list`.

```
as.list.environment <- function(env) {
  out <- base::as.list.environment(env)
  lapply(out, function(x) if (is.environment(x)) as.list(x) else x)
}
```

Then R will figure it out automatically for all future environments. If you want the old behavior in a few select places, use `base::as.list.environment` explicitly.
Example:

```
 > env <- new.env(); env$a <- new.env(); env$a$b <- 1; env$a$c <- 2; env$d <- 4
 > dput(as.list(env))
 structure(list(a = structure(list(b = 1, c = 2), .Names = c("b", "c")), d = 4), .Names = c("a", "d"))
```

Finally, you should ask yourself why you get infinite recursion if you replace  `out <- base::as.list.environment(env)` above with `out <- base::as.list(env)`.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Thought there would already be something "built-in" that's faster than this. But I guess there isn't, right?

Comment: Nice addition on how to overwrite the S3 method!

Comment: Not that I know of. :)